# Create a model attribute from checkbox input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This creates and saves a new row to my database.  The problem is that I have a checkbox in my view file for a boolean value, but no matter whether the box is checked or not, the new row is always false. I also can't get any of the other attributes to show up as anything other than nil. Any ideas?

This is my view is:

```
<%= form_for(@setting) do |s| %>
  <div class="field" >
    <%= s.label :my_setting_attribute %>
    <%= s.check_box(:my_setting_attribute) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= s.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my controller:

```
def new
  @setting = Setting.new
end

def create
  @setting = Setting.new(params[:setting])
  if @setting.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index', :id => @setting.id
  else
    redirect_to :action => 'error'
  end
end
```

I think I have my route file set correctly:

```
resources :settings do
  collection do
    get :index
    post 'settings/new'
    get 'settings/show'
  end
end
```

Here's the development log excerpt:

```
Started POST "/settings" for 10.7.94.191 at 2011-07-25 20:30:11 -0400
  Processing by SettingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxx=", "setting"=>{"my_setting_attribute"=>"1", "other_setting_attribute"=>"hello"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
ESC[1mESC[36mUser Load (0.1ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1ESC[0m
  ESC[1mESC[35mSQL (0.1ms)ESC[0m  BEGIN
  ESC[1mESC[36mSQL (1.0ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mdescribe `settings`ESC[0m
  ESC[1mESC[35mAREL (0.3ms)ESC[0m  INSERT INTO `settings` (`facebook_token`, `twitter`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `image_id`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-07-26 00:30:12', '2011-07-26 00:30:12', NULL)
ESC[1mESC[36mSQL (57.1ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mCOMMITESC[0m
Redirected to http://3000/settings?id=12
```

Comment: Have you added `attr_accessible :my_setting_attribute` to the `Setting` model ?

Comment: and can you put the development log excerpt?

Comment: I have attr_accessor in my model.

Comment: I tried switching to attr_accessible, but no change. @mikhailov let me know if there's another section of the log that'd be more helpful

Comment: where is your my_setting_attribute column? *INSERT INTO `settings` (`facebook_token`, `twitter`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `image_id`)*

Comment: How SQL looks like if the checkbox pressed?

Comment: @mikhailov sorry about that, my_setting_attribute is actually twitter

Answer (score 0):

May not be the "correct" way of doing it but you could probably do this:

In your controller for the `update` and `create` method, check what the value of `params[:my_setting_attribute]` is. You may need to conditionally set the attribute to either "true" or "false".

e.g. perhaps it is returning "1" instead of true (which your log seems to indicuate), then you can set it yourself with something like `@my_object.my_setting_attribute = true if params[:my_setting_attribute] == "1"`. Then probably add an `else` clause to set everything else to false, just to be safe.

Comment: it's good idea if the model has an attribute protected from being changed, but in that case the attribute is attr_accessible

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  Also, I wish I'd noticed this earlier, but the model actually won't save values for any of the attributes. In the log above, the other_setting_attribute is set as "hello", but in the INSERT INTO all the values are set as nil